# How to use `element.offsetParent` with HTML SVG elements?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm performing maintenance on some javascript which makes use of the [`.offsetParent`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html) property. Recent changes now have the application using SVG elements, and they are breaking the JavaScript, as `mySvgElement.offsetParent` is always `undefined`.

Is `.offsetParent` standard, and does it not work with SVG elements? If so, what is an alternative to `.offsetParent` when working with HTML5 SVG elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

offsetParent does not exist in SVG.

To get the bounding box coordinates of an SVG node, you would typically use the getBBox method on the SVG element. This returns a bbox in the local coordinate system of that element. To determine the location of the SVG element in screen coordinates, then, you use getScreenCTM on the element to get a transformation matrix that will transform that element's local coordinates to screen coordinates. You then transform the returned bbox by the returned transformation matrix. Here's some code to do this:

```
function getBoundingBoxInArbitrarySpace(element,mat){
    var svgRoot = element.ownerSVGElement;
    var bbox = element.getBBox();

    var cPt1 =  svgRoot.createSVGPoint();
    cPt1.x = bbox.x;
    cPt1.y = bbox.y;
    cPt1 = cPt1.matrixTransform(mat);

    // repeat for other corner points and the new bbox is
    // simply the minX/minY  to maxX/maxY of the four points.
    var cPt2 = svgRoot.createSVGPoint();
    cPt2.x = bbox.x + bbox.width;
    cPt2.y = bbox.y;
    cPt2 = cPt2.matrixTransform(mat);

    var cPt3 = svgRoot.createSVGPoint();
    cPt3.x = bbox.x;
    cPt3.y = bbox.y + bbox.height;
    cPt3 = cPt3.matrixTransform(mat);

    var cPt4 = svgRoot.createSVGPoint();
    cPt4.x = bbox.x + bbox.width;
    cPt4.y = bbox.y + bbox.height;
    cPt4 = cPt4.matrixTransform(mat);

    var points = [cPt1,cPt2,cPt3,cPt4]

    //find minX,minY,maxX,maxY
    var minX=Number.MAX_VALUE;
    var minY=Number.MAX_VALUE;
    var maxX=0
    var maxY=0
    for(i=0;i<points.length;i++)
    {
        if (points[i].x < minX)
        {
            minX = points[i].x
        }
        if (points[i].y < minY)
        {
            minY = points[i].y
        }
        if (points[i].x > maxX)
        {
            maxX = points[i].x
        }
        if (points[i].y > maxY)
        {
            maxY = points[i].y
        }
    }

    //instantiate new object that is like an SVGRect
    var newBBox = {"x":minX,"y":minY,"width":maxX-minX,"height":maxY-minY}
    return newBBox; 
}   

function getBBoxInScreenSpace(element){
    return getBoundingBoxInArbitrarySpace(element,element.getScreenCTM());
}
```

This code was taken from [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/sandbox/gsoc/2010/scxml-js/trunk/src/javascript/scxml/cgf/util/svg.js), and is Apache-licensed. getBoundingBoxInArbitrarySpace has been tested, but getBBoxInScreenSpace hasn't (but I think it should work).

Answer (score 4):

`offsetParent` is not a standard property of SVG elements, although some browsers may provide one anyway.

Depending on what you want to do with the information, using [`getScreenCTM`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getScreenCTM) or [`getCTM`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getCTM) will probably work for you.  For example, here's how you might calculate the position in pixels of (0, 0) relative to the element:

```
   var
       matrix = element.getScreenCTM(),
       point = element.createSVGPoint();
   point.x = 0;
   point.y = 0;
   point = point.matrixTransform(matrix.inverse());
```

Answer (score 1):

"SVGElement.offsetParent' is deprecated and will be removed in M50" = april 2016 offsetParent will be removed

**You can use "getBoundingClientRect()"**

for more info : https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5724912467574784