# d3 chloropleth losing geometry once second dataset is loaded

Tags: json, dictionary, d3.js, zooming

I appear to be losing my geometry data when I load a second JSON (containing electoral data) into a d3 chloropleth. This prevents me from calculating the bounding box when I want to zoom into a particular electoral district.

Here is Mike's code (showing USA) which zooms in and out fine when clicked but doesn't overlay any data: [democra.me/zoom_mike.htm](http://democra.me/zoom_mike.htm)

Here is my live demo (using Australia): [democra.me/federal2.htm](http://democra.me/federal2.htm)

Using the Chrome console, you'll see that Mike's correctly displays the bounds of a state while mine does not because d no longer contains feature data, causing clicked() to fail.

I want to keep the map and data in separate files for future flexibility (so I like matching the id to keep them in sync when loading) but how can I preserve the geometry into runtime?

(The tooltips are a DIV outside the SVG and don't affect the problem.)

Thx

Comment: I suspect it's because I need to use a forEach instead of trying to match the two sets on id?

Comment: If you join new data, you replace the old.  You'll need to either merge the datasets or use a hashmap to store your new data by id so you can access it without over-writing your map data, as in this choropleth example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a closer look at that.It would be handy to have a d3 method that examined SVG path data, and converted it back into feature data. This would be the opposite of the path(feature) method. This would enable an interactive use of an SVG derived from Illustrator, for example.

Comment: I have used the SVG method, element.getBBox() which works nicely to give me the position and size of the SVG element and allows the zoom to work. Thanks Amelia for at least showing I was barking up the wrong tree!

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Could you maybe write it up as an answer for anyone stumbling upon this in the future?

Comment: Glad to. It took a while to figure out that getBBox doesn't return the *transformed* SVG coordinates! So I had to borrow some code from jbeard4's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996005/how-to-use-element-offsetparent-with-html-svg-elements.
Here is the latest version of my code with visible bounding box and background to help show what's going on: http://democra.me/federal4.htm. (It doesn't work so well in IE9 right now but that's a side issue.)

Comment: Your IE9 problem is probably related to [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/781000/svg-getscreenctm-is-not-independant-of-browser-zoom).  If it's a deal-breaker for you, look at this [patch for the effect of the bug on d3.mouse](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/766) to figure out how they handled it.